# JSON com array dentro IONIC 3

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, ionic3

Gostaria de saber como eu recupero os dados vindo de uma api rest, onde eu tenho um array dentro de um Json.

Exemplo Abaixo:

```
[
  {
    "Presencas": [],
    "Turma": {
      "Alunos": [],
      "Voluntarios": [],
      "Id": 1,
      "Nome": "Futebol Pequenos",
      "IdadeMinima": 4,
      "IdadeMaxima": 10,
      "HorarioInicial": "08:00:00",
      "HorarioFinal": "09:00:00",
      "DiaSemana": "Sábado",
      "QuantidadeDeAlunos": 0
    },
    "Id": 5,
    "DataAula": "2019-01-05T00:00:00",
    "DataEnvio": "2019-01-30T21:38:42",
    "TurmaID": 1,
    "AlunosPresentes": 0
  }
]
```

Estou fazendo assim

```
this.rest.getAula().then((result: any[]) => {
    this.aulas = result;
    this.aulas.forEach(elemento => {
        console.log(elemento.Id);
    });
});
```

Mas os únicos retornados são esses

```
"Id":5,
"DataAula":"2019-01-05T00:00:00",
"DataEnvio":"2019-01-30T21:38:42",
"TurmaID":1,
"AlunosPresentes":0
```

Preciso dessas seguintes informações

```
{
  "Turma": {
    "Alunos": [],
    "Voluntarios": [],
    "Id": 1,
    "Nome": "Futebol Pequenos",
    "IdadeMinima": 4,
    "IdadeMaxima": 10,
    "HorarioInicial": "08:00:00",
    "HorarioFinal": "09:00:00",
    "DiaSemana": "Sábado",
    "QuantidadeDeAlunos": 0
  }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: já tentou `elemento[0]['Turma']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem certeza que vai ser sempre um valor no array ou que sempre vai pegar o primeiro valor:

```
const turma = result && result.length > 0 ? 
               dados[0].Turma :  // primeira turma no array
               null; // vazio se nao existir

console.log(turma);
```

Caso queira filtrar os valores e retornar uma lista de turmas por id, você pode utilizar:

```
function encontrarTurmaPorId(id: string): any {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray
  if (!Array.isArray(dados)) {
    return []; // Nenhuma turma
  }


  // Filtra valores e retorna apenas turmas com ID específico
  // Recomendo trocar o "any" pela sua interface/tipo
  const turmas = dados.filter((items: Array<any>) => items.Turma.Id === id);

  return turmas;
}

console.log(encontrarTurmaPorId(1)); // retorna lista de turmas com id 1
```

Comment: dessa maneira não deu certo, preciso exibir esse dados na tela  



Nome": "Futebol Pequenos",
    "IdadeMinima": 4,
    "IdadeMaxima": 10,
    "HorarioInicial": "08:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Eai man, seguinte. Se você está querendo pegar os dados direto da API, faz assim:

Cria uma variável global assim:

```
http: Http;
```

Depois capturar os dados da API dessa forma:

```
 var aula;
    this.http.get('link/para/sua/api').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        aula = data;
        console.log(aula);
    });
```

Comment: não há nenhum método .json () no novo HttpClientModule